# another meaning of 'make a run'

Tags: meaning

> I overheard Alex talking to his brother-in-law, Bobby, about ***making
>   a… a run***.

Is there an another meaning of 'making a run'?

This is a dialogue from a TV show.
And Alex who is a mayor candidate committed a crime.
So he wants to cover it.
He doesn't want to run away.

However, I found 'make a run' in dictionary and It says 'escape' 'attempt to win/or do something'.
So I wonder there is an another meaning of 'making a run' that makes sense of this dialogue.

Please help me understand it perfectly!
(My native language is not English, please be kind to me. :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Make a run" can, in some contexts, mean "make an attempt".  Very often you hear this in the setting of "make a run for office", meaning to present oneself as a candidate for a political office.

In your limited context it's a little unclear what precise meaning is intended.

Comment: I know this context is limited. But, thank you for telling me about another meaning of 'Make a run'. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Making a run *for **it***

To abscond - possibly to avoid legal attention

> Making a run *for **[goods]***

To go to the shop, get the goods, then come back

> Making a run *for **office***

Attempt to get elected into office

> Making a run *of leaflets*

To print a **batch** of leaflets

> Making a run *in my stocking* (Thanks Hot Licks)

To cause a *ladder/hole* in the material of your stockings

> Making a run *in cricket*

To score 1 point in cricket by running to the opposite wicket (unlikely in this context)

This list is not exhaustive - there are also other '*runs*' you could make (eg you could make a run for mountain bikes, a bobsleigh run, a run on a bank) but I'll leave commenters to add these

Comment: You left out "make a run in my stocking".

Answer (score 1):

Make a run to buy something. Eg: "Make a coffee run"

Granted without specifying what you're running for the common assumption is something criminal but it would give plausible deniability.

Comment: Also for another excuse he could claim he said "take a run" which just means attempting something. eg "take a run at convincing [district] to vote for me".

Comment: My assumption is 'making a run' is political without any other context. But perhaps we aren't too far apart...